# Sed command for recursive find and replace failing

Tags: linux, macos, sed, replace

I am trying a recursive find and replace command on my `OSX` as so :

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sed -i '' s/Renseigner votre question en 140 caractères max/Renseigner votre question en 140 caractères max./ {} +
```

but I am getting this :

```
sed: 1: "s/Renseigner": unterminated substitute pattern
sed: 1: "s/Renseigner": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Someone knows why ?

Comment: Solved, I had simply to escape the white spaces !

Comment: No, that is the wrong thing to do as there's a lot more pitfalls than just dealing with spaces. Put your substitution in single quotes instead: `'s/foo/bar/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around the sed command.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I managed to make it work. Btw, do you know how could write a script in order to enter the strings to be found and replaced, something like : #!bin/bash find . -type f -name '.' -exec sed -i '' s/$1/$2/ {} + Does it make sense, how can I then input the strings in the shell ?

Comment: @user1611830 yes, use double quote then.

Comment: you mean double quotes wrapping "$1" and "$2" ?

Comment: Not exactly: `"s/$1/$2/"` might be adequate if your strings are simple.